# Get information about a IP address or hostname

Tags: wireless-networking, bash, terminal, ip, python

1. How to get information about a device with it's IP address or hostname with python or bash ?
2. How to get list of devices connected to the same wifi router with python or bash ?

Comment: Take a look at `arp` in bash to get connected devices, and look at `nslookup` or `dig` to reverse lookup IP address.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question first need to know your location respect to the network you try to get information.

If you belong to same local network, common Linux command `arp` will give you information about list of device connected to same local network via WiFi. `arp` will give you information which can be pursued with bash script.

To get information about a device with IP address or hostname, `nmap` will be another utility to scan and analyze target device. This utility is not restricted to work inside local network but any connected device anywhere can be analyze with this. Just have to be reachable by your host.